# Generalize expand.grid function

Tags: r

I have a R function.

```
expand.grid(paste(names(mtcars),seq(-10,10)))
```

Here what I am trying to do is, for every column name of *mtcars* I want to assign a sequence from -10 to 10.

When I use above code I am getting some different output.

**Desired output:**

```
st1 <- expand.grid(Const = seq(-100, 100, len = 4),
                   B = seq(-100, 100, len = 4),
                   A = seq(-1, 1, len = 4))
```

In this example we are creating 4 observation under every variable (Const, A and B). Likewise I want to create 20 observations under column names of `mtcars`.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Maybe `expand.grid(names(mtcars),seq(-10,10))`?

Comment: 'st1 <- expand.grid(Const = seq(-100, 100, len = 4),
B = seq(-100, 100, len = 4), A = seq(-1, 1, len = 4))'. In this example we are creating 4 observation under every variable(Const,A and B). Like wise i want to create 20 observations under column names of mtcars.

Comment: Please edit your original post.